# TFS Build keeps 'in progress' state without finishing build with error or success [TFS 2012]

Tags: tfs

I created a new build definition.

Then "Queue new build ..."

Build state changes its value to 'In progress'

And... that's all !

No errors, no result

Here is the activity log

**user1 triggered SimpleWeb(Test_BuildDeploy) for latest sources
Running for 0 seconds (vm-tfs-Controller)**

Comment: try queuing it in verbose mode, it should be in the second tab when you queue the build

Comment: How can I enable verbose mode? The second tab is 'Completed' tab

Comment: second tab when queueuing the build, in the popup window.

Comment: Can you post link to screenshot? please

Comment: which build process template are you using, have you tried rebooting your build server?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Anyone have a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Try upping logging verbosity to diagnostic - screenshot as requested
[image: Try upping logging verbosity to diagnostic]

Comment: Thanks for screenshot. But the same result with no additional log entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have no solution for this, then check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387652/build-never-starts-on-tfs2012/15387988#15387988) here on SO. It is the same one and I had the same problem also once.